# Coredata relationship creation

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I have an entity called EntityA containing a relationship to another entity (which is not optional, with a 1--1 relationship) called EntityB, I would like that when I create EntityA, one instance of EntityB is automatically created.

Is possible?

Also I am using a CoreData model versioning. In my next version I am introducing this new entity (EntityB) into EntityA, the problem is that I am unable to save object EntityA since entityB has not been created before.

Is it possible that during CoreData merges (which will add EntityB in DB scheme), this new relationship is created?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Thierry

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, you could automatically create EntityB by adding logic to create one and setup the relationship in the `didAwakeFromInsert` method of EntityA.

I think you would have to handle your second issue similarly. What you could do is add logic to the `didAwakeFromFetch` method of EntityA to check for the existence of the relationship with EntityB and create an EntityB if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is by setting the relationship in a generated NSManagedObject subclass. I highly encourage you to check out a tool called mogenerator (http://rentzsch.github.io/mogenerator/) as that will allow you to continually make changes to your core data model without losing all of the custom code you add to the core data entity subclasses. Mogenerator can be setup to automatically generate new subclasses whenever you change your model without destroying the custom code you've written to handle the core data entities. It's well worth the time investment to learn it if you plan on using core data in a serious way.

To generate these files manually (without mogenerator) you simply click on your core data model file in XCode, select the entity you would like to create a subclass for, click on the 'Editor' menu and select 'Create NSManagedObject Subclass...'

This will create two files, a EntityA.h and EntityA.m (or EntityB depending on which entity you have selected when you click on the menu item). Do this same process again for the other entity to generate its files (note: make sure you have the relationship setup before you generate these files or you will have to regenerate them!).

I then usually create class methods like this:

```
//In EntityA.h
//between @interface and @end...
+ (EntityA*)createNewEntityAInContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context;


//In EntityA.m
+ (EntityA*)createNewEntityAInContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context
{
    EntityA* aEntityAObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"EntityA" inManagedObjectContext:context]

    EntityB* aEntityBObject = [EntityB createNewEntityBInContext:context];
    aEntityAObject.entityBLink = aEntityBObject;

    return aEntityAObject;
}


//In EntityB.h
//between @interface and @end...
+ (EntityB*)createNewEntityBInContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context;

//In EntityB.m
+ (EntityB*)createNewEntityBInContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context
{
    EntityB* aEntityBObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"EntityB" inManagedObjectContext:context]

    return aEntityBObject;
}
```

You can then call your +createNewEntityAInContext: method whenever you wanted a new object and the relationship will automatically be created.

Regarding your other question, what you are looking for is called a custom core data migration policy. You can search for a tutorial on that subject in google and there are plenty of links. Here's one I found that looked pretty good at first glance: http://9elements.com/io/index.php/customizing-core-data-migrations/